# no match for call to (class)(type) in constructor

Tags: c++, class, templates, struct, constructor

I'm attempting to define a non-type template class constructor but it is giving me the following error when I call the constructor of a struct member of the class:

```
error: no match for call to ‘(ByteVector) (unsigned int)’
         Key(N);
         ^~~
```

Here is the AES constructor, which is also the offending code:

```
template <unsigned int N>
AES<N>::AES(Mode mode) : IV(BLOCKSIZE), Block(BLOCKSIZE), SubKey(BLOCKSIZE), mode(mode)
{
    try
    {
        if(N == 256 || N == 192 || N == 128)
        {
            Key(N);
            switch(N)
            {
                case 256: RoundNum = 14; break;
                case 192: RoundNum = 12; break;
                case 128: RoundNum = 10; break;
                default: break; // This should never be reached
            }
        }
        else
            throw "Size Error in AES constructor. Valid sizes: 256, 192, 128";
    } catch (char const *e)
    {
        std::cerr << e << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

The ByteVector is a simple struct which is passed an unsigned int that gives initializes the size:

```
ByteVector::ByteVector(unsigned int s)
{
    size = s / 8;
    for(int i = 0; i < s; i++) data.push_back(0);
}
```

Here are the stripped down class definitions:

```
typedef uint8_t Byte;
typedef struct ByteVector
{
    std::vector<Byte> data;
    int size;
    ByteVector();
    ByteVector(unsigned int size);
} ByteVector;


template <unsigned int N>
class AES
{
    public:
        AES();
        AES(Mode mode);
    protected:
        ByteVector IV;
        ByteVector Block;
        ByteVector Key;
        ByteVector SubKey;
        Mode mode;
        uint8_t RoundNum;
};
```

The AES methods are defined in a .tcc file which is included just below the class definitions in the AES.hh file

If you put Key(N) in the initialization list of the AES constructor, it does not complain, but because I am performing checks on the size of N, I do not think it should go in the initialization list.

However if you place the calls in the initialization list into the body of the AES constructor, it complains of issues for them as well.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Off topic: If you only allow three numbers rather than a wide range of integers, consider replacing the integer with an `enum`.

Comment: Interesting, why do you suggest that change?

Comment: I'd suggest using compile-time techniques to avoid the switch..break stuff, this will make your code a lot cleaner, and will enable you to move Key's initialization to the ctor-initializers.  You want a "wrong" number to generate a compilation error, not wait until runtime

Comment: Partly for readability, but mostly because the compiler can easily trap an instantiation using a value that is not in the enum. Why test at runtime something known and resolvable at compile time?

Comment: You're right, it makes much more sense that way. I'm modifying it to an enum. Thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to *construct* the `Key` object? You can't do it like that in the body of a function.

Either do it in the constructor initializer list together with the other member variables, or use assignment:

```
Key = ByteVector{N};
```

---

What you are doing now is attempting to use the function-call operator on the `Key` object, and since the structure doesn't have such an operator you get an error.

Comment: Ah such a simple fix! Thank you. I'll accept this as the correct answer as soon as the time limit is up